# How to read a single line from file in java

Tags: java

How can i read single line from a text file in java.
and what is the criteria of knowing that line is completed.

secondly

i read file and then for Read Line function and converting it into string will skip a lot of data? what should be the problem?
Here is my code

```
String data = new String();
    while(infile.readLine() != null) {
    data = infile.readLine();
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your code as follows

```
  while((data = infile.readLine()) != null) {  // read and store only line    
  System.out.println(data);
  }
```

In your current code

```
   while(infile.readLine() != null) { // here you are reading one and only line
   data = infile.readLine(); // there is no more line to read
    System.out.println(data);
   }
```

Comment: Now it will read all data but gives exception how could it get rid of it

13
13
0 5
4 3
0 1
9 12
6 4
5 4
0 2
11 12
9 10
0 6
7 8
9 11
5 3

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at assignment.main(assignment.java:14)

Comment: @DaNyAlmAlIk how is your code looks like now? try with `debug` your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading an extra line because the first `readLine()` as the `while` condition reads a line but it is used at all. The second `readLine()` inside the `while` loop read the second line which you're assigning to `data` and printing.

Therefore you need to assign the line read in the `while` condition to `data` and print it, as that is the first line.

```
while((data = infile.readLine()) != null) { // reads the first line
    // data = infile.readLine(); // Not needed, as it reads the second line
    System.out.println(data); // print the first line
}
```

Also, since you just need to read the first line, you don't need the `while` at all. A simple `if` would do.

```
if((data = infile.readLine()) != null) { // reads the first line
    System.out.println(data); // print the first line
}
```

With the `BufferedReader` and the code you posted in the comments, your main should now look like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
        BufferedReader infile = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                fstream));
        String data = new String();
        while ((data = infile.readLine()) != null) { // use if for reading just 1 line
            System.out.println(data);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Error
    }
}
```

Comment: the data in file is 

13 
15
2 3 
0 6 
0 1 
2 0 
11 12  
9 12  
9 10  
9 11 
3 5 
8 7 
5 4 
0 5 
6 4 
6 9 
7 6

but the output on console is

13
13
0 5
4 3
0 1
9 12
6 4
5 4
0 2
11 12
9 10
0 6
7 8
9 11
5 3


????

Comment: read line() must be converted into string as it is not already in string. or it gives an error of type casting

Comment: Which reader are you using to read from the file? I suggest you use a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: i got you and i just use that readline() once but it still skips many values and also repeating some as well.

Comment: i have posted the question again in detail with output. please have a look on it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324036/here-is-my-compete-code-of-that-issue-of-reading-file

Comment: @DaNyAlmAlIk - Its just better to close this and create a new one. And if the question is the same, then edit the current question instead of creating duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

First thing : `readLine()` returns String value only so it is not converting to String.

Second thing : In your while loop, you read firstline and check whether the content of first line is null or not. But when `data = infile.readLine();` executes, it will fetch second line from file and print it to Console.

Change your while loop to this :

```
while((data = infile.readLine()) != null){ 
    System.out.println(data); 
}
```

If you use `toString()` method, it will throw NPE when it will try to use `toString` method with `null` content read from `infile`.

Comment: Now it will read all data but gives exception how could it get rid of it

13
13
0 5
4 3
0 1
9 12
6 4
5 4
0 2
11 12
9 10
0 6
7 8
9 11
5 3

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at assignment.main(assignment.java:14)

Comment: @DaNyAlmAlIk Can you please update your code in above question so that I can understand the problem clearly

Comment: And what is line number 14 in assignment.java file

Comment: import java.util.Iterator;

public class assignment {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  In infile = new In(args[0]);
  
//  Digraph digraph = new Digraph(infile);
 // System.out.println(digraph.toString());
  
  String data = new String();
  try {
   while((data = infile.readLine().toString()) != null){
    System.out.println(data);   
   }
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
   
  }
 }

}
 this is the complete code