# Here is my complete code of that issue of reading file

Tags: java

Please have a look at the code for reading line by line data from a text file.

```
import java.util.Iterator;

public class assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      In infile = new In(args[0]);

      String data = new String();
      try {
          while((data = infile.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(data);           
          }
      } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      }
   }
}
```

here is the In class and Digraphs is not using co i removed it

```
public final class In {

    private Scanner scanner;
    public In(String s) {
    try {
        // first try to read file from local file system
        File file = new File(s);
        lines = 0;
        if (file.exists()) {
            scanner = new Scanner(file, charsetName);
            scanner.useLocale(usLocale);
            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                lines++;
            }
            return;
        }

        // next try for files included in jar
        URL url = getClass().getResource(s);

        // or URL from web
        if (url == null) { url = new URL(s); }

        URLConnection site = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is     = site.getInputStream();
        scanner            = new Scanner(new BufferedInputStream(is), charsetName);
        scanner.useLocale(usLocale);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Could not open " + s);
    }
}
```

here is the read line function

```
public String readLine() {
    String line;
    try                 { line = scanner.nextLine(); }
    catch (Exception e) { line = null;               }
    return line;
}
```

here is the actual data in text file

```
13
15
2 3 
0 6 
0 1 
2 0 
11 12  
9 12  
9 10  
9 11 
3 5 
8 7 
5 4 
0 5 
6 4 
6 9 
7 6
```

and here is the output in console

```
13
13
0 5
4 3
0 1
9 12
6 4
5 4
0 2
11 12
9 10
0 6
7 8
9 11
5 3
```

i don't know why it is repeating and missing the values. the

```
ReadLine()
```

function call

```
ReadNext()
```

function

Comment: even if i didn't convert readline tostring() but still it gives the same output

Comment: Why are you calling `toString()` on a string, and why are you initializing `data` when you don't need to? Note that if you don't call `toString()`, you don't need to catch `NullPointerException` - which you shouldn't.

Comment: It also doesn't help that we have no idea what the `Digraph` and `In` classes do.

Comment: Its better you close [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20323597/2024761) first by [accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/216721) there and then move on to the next question.

Comment: this code is not complete

Comment: i have edited the code please check and ignore the Digraph as i am not using it now. only using In class and i uploaded its required functions

Comment: chances are that the args[0] is not the file you have showed here.

Comment: Ok found the error in file. thankyou for responce